# variable array duplicating / skipping one item when writing

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    var dates =["09/27/2014","12/19/2013","01/13/2015",""];
    var departments = ["Item1","Item2","item3",""];
    var writespeed = 400;
    $('.department_name').html(departments[fade-1]);
    $('.date_name').html(dates[fade-1]);
```

Comment: Can you add the code how you are calling the writeText function?

Comment: Where/when is `writeText()` called? How/when is `fade` adjusted?

Comment: `fade` seems to be not updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing but assigning a new variable worked.

```
var z = 1;
```

and then:

```
z++;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the following line of code:

```
$('.department_name').html(departments[fade-1]);
```

The issue is that in your loop, "**fade**", is not incremented. You can either use `fade++` or assign it to a different variable and increment it.

Comment: How do either of these answers account for the fact that `Item3` *is* being printed?

Comment: Could you provide an example with how to implement? So, far all attempts have failed with this solution. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Its hard to tell from just the jquery, but I believe 'fade' needs to be incremented:

```
var fade = 1;
    var depart_time = 1000;
    console.log(0,fade);
    $('.shutter').removeClass('closed-shutter open-move opened-shutter close-move');
    function writeText(args) {
        var dates =["09/27/2014","04/26/2014","03/17/2015"];
        var departments = ["Item1","Item2","Item3"];
        var writespeed = 700;
        $('.write-text').each(function(){
            $('.department_name').html(departments[fade-1]);
            $('.date_name').html(dates[fade-1]);
            fade++;
            $(this).width('auto');
            var w = $(this).width();
            $(this).width(0).animate({width:w+'px'}, writespeed, function(){
                if ($(this).hasClass('patient_name')) {
                    $(this).removeClass('write-text');
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: THIS BROKE MY ENTIRE ANIMATION